# Route Prefix VS Controller Name ( Web api )

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-routing, attributerouting

I was wondering that if we use `RoutePrefix` attribute in our web api controller with a different name from controller's actual name. So would it work or not?

As far as i did

```
[RouterPrefix("quotation")]
public class SaleOrderController : ApiController { ... }
```

if we define `RoutePrefix` like above we can't access it via `/quotation` but we can access it using `saleorder`.

So what is `RoutePrefix` for or am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: Make sure that attribute routing is enabled first `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes()` then the route prefix will work as expected. https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: its enabled but still not working because i don't want to add Routes on every method because if i do so my route would be `/quotation/getall` and that's not correct . I think it should be `/quotation` for Get

Comment: You use the default route `Route("")` on the getall method. But you have to use it if you are implementing attribute routing. it's in the name

Comment: yes, that's perfect. This is the thing i was missing. Thanks bro!

Comment: @Nkosi in visual studio if you create web api controller, config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes() is added to WebApiConfig.cs automatically.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use default route use `Route("")`

```
[RoutePrefix("quotation")]
public class SaleOrderController : ApiController {

    //GET quotation
    [Route("")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAll() { ... }

}
```

Source: [Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2 : Route Prefix](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#prefixes)

Comment: @Willmore typo on my part when I copied the code from OP. Fixed. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 4):

In order for it to work, you need to call the code below inside your `WebApiConfig.Register()` method:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

So your `RoutePrefix` works as exptected:

```
[RoutePrefix("quotation")]
public class SaleOrderController : ApiController
{
    [Route("example")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Example()
    {
        return Ok();
    }

    [Route("another")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Another()
    {
        return Ok();
    }

}
```

So your could access your apis like this:

- quotation/example
- quotation/another

Comment: What if i didn't add route to my methods in specific controller ?

Comment: @AhsanAttari, Route and RoutePrefix work hand in hand. https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: When you want to work with routing, you should add `[Route]` to every action. If you wanted a route to your controller's **route prefix**, you could do like @Nkosi suggested.